# LibGDX - Splash Screen timer isn't working

Tags: libgdx

I want a timer that switches screens after a certain amount of time. Here is the code for my splash screen:

```
private boolean timerIsOn = false;
```

And here is the render() method code:

```
      if(!timerIsOn) {
          timerIsOn = true;

          Timer.*schedule*(new Task() {

             @Override
             public void run() {
                *changeScreen*();
             }

          }, 15);

       } else if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            // Remove the task so we don't call changeScreen twice: 
            Timer.instance().clear(); 
            *changeScreen*();
      }
}
```

I'm getting red swiggly lines under the parts of the code that have * and * surrounding them but the suggested action to fix it doesn't help.

Also, if you know of an easier way to make this work or possibly a tutorial that would be great as well.

Comment: What do the errors that cause the squiggly lines say?

Comment: They say create method 'Change screen()' but even when i do that it just adds a line of code and it doesn't really fix anything much. Also the error is "Change to ScheduleTask(..)" and when I do that it just gives me another error that tells me to change it back.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html), the `schedule` method you're using does exist. Are you use you imported the LibGDX `Timer` and not the [standard Java `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?

Comment: Sorry but I new at this so I don't completely understand what you mean. I'm following this tutorial, so I just copied/pasted the code but it gives me errors. http://atsiitech.blogspot.com/2013/09/adding-15-second-timer-to-your-games.html

Comment: At the very top of your application, where all the other `import` statements are, you should have 
`import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer`. It could be that you have `import java.util.Timer` instead; you'll need to remove it if so.

Comment: Nope, I imported the right thing. If you know of a tutorial or an different way to do this please let me know.